# How can i get list of MAC address and IP address of computer through java?

Tags: java

I m developing a software where i need the list of IP address and MAC address of computer through java code. Is there any way to get the list of ip address and mac address?

Thanks

Comment: You must search the internet for an answer before posting a question. 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its very well explained in this tutorial...Pls see this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since JDK 1.6, Java developers are able to access network card detail via NetworkInterface class.

```
            InetAddress ip;
    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

    NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

    byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

    System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

For multiple ip addresses :

```
                    java.util.Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        NetworkInterface iface = en.nextElement();
        List<InterfaceAddress> addrs = iface.getInterfaceAddresses();
        //For each network interfaces iterate through each ip address
        for(InterfaceAddress addr : addrs) {
                         ip = addr.getAddress();
                          //Process the IP ...
```

Comment: This code is ok for single ip in computer, but what if there are multiple ip addresses in a single computer.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code  to run commands from java program,

```
    Process p;
    String cmd="ifconfig-a";
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("line: " + s);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
    p.destroy();
```

Output:

```
line: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:D3:DE:5A:A4  --->MAC address in linux
```

Comment: can you please define what is p variable here